# Overlay of any app is positioned incorrectly

Tags: applications, bug

[image] Here's an image of a problem I got when bought a second monitor. It does not appear on my primary one. Has anyone ran into the same problem? Any app with overlay, downloaded from app store, is behaving itself the same way. Things 3, Telegram for instance.

Software update, smc and nvram resets proved themselves useless as usual

Ventura 13.0.1 (22A400), MacBook Air M1 16gb

Comment: What is the model and brand of the external monitor, and how are you connecting it to your MBA?

Comment: I don't think it matters, just tried another one. BUT it may happen cuz they both were connected via DELL Thunderbolt dock. It might do sth

Comment: Well, you _didn't_ mention you were using a DELL Thunderbolt Dock. :-)

Comment: yeah sry just realized it may cause some stuff. so what do you think it is?